# Need help to verify the steps to my Inverse Kinematics solution

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse, quaternions, kinematics

I am trying to implement the Jacobian IK solution in my program.

I have a single kinematic chain with N rotational or transnational joints. The implementation is independent of configuration (i.e I want to be able to solve this for any input system)

The paper I am basing this on is this one
[http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15464-s13/lectures/lecture6/iksurvey.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E15464-s13/lectures/lecture6/iksurvey.pdf)

I don't have code written for it yet, just the pseudo implementation steps.
I want to verify these steps are correct before I proceed

I understand its possibly faster to convert each matrix to a quaternion first, then do the multiplication. This will be in the next revision if this works

```
// 1.  Save min and max (position or rotation) variable Θ for each of N joints, 
//     start with each joint in the middle position, choose Δ to be some small value

    //Compute Jacobian
// 2.  Find transformation matrices for current value Θ for each joint
//     (Call them #M matrix)

// 3.  Find transformation matrices for Θ+Δ and Θ-Δ of each joint independently from the 
//     current position (Call them #M+ and #M- matrices)

// 4.  Multiply (1M+)·(2M)·(3M)·(4M)... and (1M-)·(2M)·(3M)·(4M)...  to get 
//     F1M+ and F1M- matrices

// 5.  Convert F1M+ and F1M- to quaternion and translation vectors, combine into 1 vector 
//     [qw, qx, qy, qz, x, y, z] 

// 6.  Subtract (F1M+)-(F1M-) vectors 

// 7.  These 7 variables become first column of the Jacobian matrix

// 8.  Repeat steps 4-7 for 2M+-, 3M+-, etc to complete 
//     Jacobian matrix with N columns and 7 rows

    //Compute Error
// 9.  Compute (1M)·(2M)·(3M)·(4M)... convert to quaternion plus translation vector denote 
//     as 7 axis vector S

// 10. Take end effector matrix, convert to quaterion plus translation vector denote 
//     as 7 axis vector T (only needs to be done once)

// 11. Find E = T - S

    //Update Θ
// 12. Solve equation E = J · ΔΘ for ΔΘ using Jᵀ·E = Jᵀ·J·ΔΘ  then (Jᵀ·J)¯¹·Jᵀ·E = ΔΘ

// 13. Add ΔΘ to current Θ
    
// 14. Repeat Steps 2-13 Until E is sufficiently small or 
//     T¯¹·S is close enough to identity matrix
```